# Finding p-value of similarity between 2 networks

Tags: hypergeometric-distribution, subset

So, I want to calculate p-value of a case if possible.

Suppose I have:

- set A with 1,295 elements
- set B with 493 elements
- number of same element between set A and B (intersection) is 478

From each set, I draw an edge between the element. Basically I create a network of element using some method.

- The number of edge that I can define for set A is 87,637
- The number of edge that I can define for set B is 12,863
- number of same edge (intersection) is 1,606

What I want to test is degree of significance of the intersection edge. Is it possible to calculate?

Comment: You're gonna have to explain what these edges are with context. Also what is significance in this case?

Comment: Well, so the context is a biological network. So each node is a gene. Edges means a gene regulate target gene. I want to compare my method with previously published network. The method is similar, it is just that I use more data and different parameter. I want to see if my output network is similar or not. Because it is using same method but different parameter, I want to validate my network with previous network.

Comment: There are no tests for comparing whole networks (as far as I know). If I understand correctly, you want to measure a degree of concordance / agreement between two networks (only the intersection subset)? If so, how do you want to do that? What metric?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I want to figure out.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index, it's used for clustering but maybe it is related to your task.